# Extracting Data Client Side

Tags: sql-server, etl, ssis

I need to be able to extract and transform data from a data source on a client machine and ship it off via a web service call to be loaded into our data store. I would love to be able leverage SSIS but the Sql Server licensing agreement is preventing me from installing Integration Services on a client machine. Can I just provide the client copies of the Integration Services' assemblies to be referenced by my app? Does anyone have any ideas on how to best implement a solution to this problem apart from building a custom solution from the ground up? Ideally the solution would include leveraging an existing ETL tool?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you run SSIS on the target server?

Comment: Yes, I believe I can run SSIS on the target server.

Comment: From comments below, I believe you mean "Client's machine" rather than "client machine" which implies a workstation on your network rather than a machine on a network belonging to a client of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are providing your client with a service around their data, you should develop a standard that they need to deliver their data in, and negotiate a delivery method for that file well before you ever consider what to do with SSIS.  Since from comments it appears that your data is on a machine in a client's remote location, the most common method I have seen is either having the client SecureFTP a file into your network for processing, or to have a job on your end that gets the file using SecureFTP. Once you have the file on your network, writing the SSIS to process it is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If the server can reach out to the client machine, then you can just run the SSIS package on the server.  What kind of data are you moving?  If it's a flat file, you could FTP it to the server.

Another way to go about this is to use BCP.  I'm not a big fan of this approach (SSIS is much faster, more robust, etc), but it can work in a pinch.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Comment: The data sources could be anything ... a flat file, database, etc. We need to build several different types of "providers" to extract the data. Also, the extraction is not a one time thing ... new data is extracted from the source system every X minutes. Unfortunately I can not copy or move the source data file from the client.

Comment: Can you make the file, database, etc available across the network (share the file, hit the database with OLEDB/ODBC/etc) from the server?  If so, you can schedule the SSIS package(s) to run on the server every X minutes.

And why can't you copy or move the data file from the client?  Is the server only supposed to see a subset of the data or something?

Comment: A client's data is protected by a firewall and they want to share only a subset of it.